# Excel 2007 - Why do hidden rows and columns all unhide when inputting a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have certain rows and columns hidden in my workbook. When I input a formula, all those hidden rows and columns unhide. Is there a way to keep those rows and columns hidden during the input of a formula?

Comment: This is a question regarding use of Excel, not about programming or creating a complex formula. As such, it's off-topic here. It's better suited for [su] instead. This site is for programming (code) and programmer's tools related questions. The [help] has more information. Good luck.

Comment: I find it odd to put a formula in a hidden cell. All the same, I just tried it and the hidden column doesn't unhide on my Excel-2007.

Answer (score -1):

You can use separate worksheets for your formulas and protect them by passwords. Then formulas in this worksheet don't get visible, but you can access the values calculated inside the protected worksheet. 
When protecting the worksheet, any kind of access to this worksheet has to be forbidden for "all users".